# mysql left join get two queries

Tags: mysql

ok i have two tables, houses and pictures. what i would like to call is 
for each house i would like to call number of pictures for that house and also minimum sort_order number for that photo.

i tried left join in different types, one returns me total photos which is fine ,but doesnt return the min sort order, the other one returns me min sort order but doesnt give me total photos.

my current code is

```
SELECT properties.p_id,                                         properties.s_property_id,                                   properties.a_property_id,
                            properties.p_advert_heading,                                properties.p_postcode,                                      properties.p_price,
                            properties.p_bedrooms,                                      properties.p_bathrooms,                                     properties.p_status,                                        
                            properties.p_priority,                                      property_photos.photo_url,                              property_photos.sort_order, property_photos.photo_local,                                    
                            COUNT(property_photos.p_id) AS tot_photos                                       
                            FROM properties 
                            LEFT JOIN property_photos on properties.p_id = property_photos.p_id                         
                            WHERE  properties.is_archieved = 0 AND properties.p_status = 1 AND  properties.a_id = 16 
                            GROUP BY properties.p_id
```

ie:

```
house_table
----------
property_id
property_name

photo_table
-----------
photo_id
property_id
sort_order
```

so i need to find total number of pictures and also the id of the photo with minimum sort_order...

Comment: edited my question and added the code jonathon

Comment: Why doesn't `min(sort_order)` do what you want?

Comment: i have sorted with another sub query but can not write it as i dont have enough reputation but thank yo uto all for your time to help me . greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get both values most easily by using the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` method to get the first `photo_id`:

```
select property_id, count(*) as numphotos,
       substring_index(group_concat(photo_id order by sort_order), ',', 1) as min_photo_id
from photo_table pt
group by property_id;
```

Comment: Why do all that instead of using simple aggregation functions?

Comment: @MikeBrant . . . Because this is a single aggregation function with no joins.  It should perform better than other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `GROUP BY` and aggregation functions:

```
SELECT
    h.property_id,
    h.property_name,
    COUNT(p.photo_id) AS photo_count,
    MIN(p.sort_order) AS min_sort
FROM house_table AS h
LEFT JOIN photo_table AS p
  ON h.property_id = p.property_id
GROUP BY h.property_id
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't return the property that has the minimum sort order.  However, I'm not impolite enough to downvote your answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The problem statement would seem to indicate that the OP is looking for the minimum sort order value for each property, not the single property with the lowest sort order value.

Comment: The statement "also minimum sort_order number for that photo" indicates both that the OP struggles with English and that s/he is interested in some photo.  I interpret this as the "photo with the minimum sort order for the house"; it seems like the only reasonable interpretation to me.